# Nutch Crawling: During generate, is it possible to use more than a single reducer?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, web-crawler, nutch

I'm using nutch 2.x for a crawl where each batch of urls contains about 3 -5 million.

I'm running in a distributed mode, using a 100 node hadoop cluster with an HBase backend. The urls are from thousands of different domains.

Inject runs quickly, but the generate phase can take 2 - 4 hours to complete. It only ever uses a single reducer. The map stage uses multiple mappers, depending on the input size. But always only one reducer.

My question: is it possible to increase the number of reducers used in the generate job, and if so, what needs to be done?

I've searched far and wide for an answer but haven't found anything.

Comment: Look into threading

Comment: Are you running Nutch in a distributed environment (cluster)? The URLs are for the same domain/host?

Comment: Updated the question to include those details, which are yes I am running in a distributed environment. It's a 100 node hadoop cluster. The urls are spread across thousands of different domains. (didn't mean to up-vote your comment).

Comment: @BenderBending I'm not able to find anything on google about threading with nutch during the generate phase. 
Are you saying to look into threading in a general sense or are you aware of a threading feature in nutch generate I can use?

Comment: What is the configuration of the `mapreduce.job.reduces` setting for your hadoop cluster? How many fetch segments are generated after the generator has finished? there are a few factors that impact how the generator job generate the fetch segments.